# Version 2.17 - WGS is not defined

Tags: autodesk-viewer

Updating from v2.16 to v2.17, I have downloaded the viewer and model files to use them locally.  If I use the local version, I get an error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: WGS is not defined
    at new f (viewer3D.min.js?v=v2.17:10)
    at a.e.loadModel (viewer3D.min.js?v=v2.17:20)
    at a.loadModel (viewer3D.min.js?v=v2.17:22)
    at Object.initialize (viewer-embed.js:125)
    at HTMLDocument.initialize (model:198)
f @ viewer3D.min.js?v=v2.17:10
e.loadModel @ viewer3D.min.js?v=v2.17:20
a.loadModel @ viewer3D.min.js?v=v2.17:22
initialize @ viewer-embed.js:125
initialize @ model:198
```

It appears that WGS.min.js is no longer loading before this line is executed?   Current fix is to include it explicitly:

```
<script src="/Scripts/viewers/three.min.js?v=v2.17"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/viewers/WGS.min.js?v=v2.17"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/viewers/viewer3D.min.js?v=v2.17"></script>
```

Edit:
Debugged through `viewer3d.js` to track the loading of `WGS.js`, and it appears that my call to `loadModel()` with the url of the local model is happening too soon, and before WGS.js has finished loading.

Not sure why I had the `loadModel()` call after `Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer()` instead of in the callback to it, but moved it into the callback and it works.  Now not sure how it ever worked with previous versions, but working now.

Comment: Alan, still having problems?

Comment: Had another look at it and think I have found the bug in my code.  Edited the question with a better fix than the original workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have local version of these files? The `viewer3d.js` will load additional files, including `wgs.js` and `lmvworker.js`

Just tried the following and it's working fine ([from here](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/tutorials/basic-viewer/)):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/derivativeservice/v2/viewers/style.min.css?v=v2.17" type="text/css">
<script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/derivativeservice/v2/viewers/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/derivativeservice/v2/viewers/viewer3D.min.js?v=v2.17"></script>
```